# Optional Router Params with @ngrx

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects

Similar to the ngrx/example-app, I am building an interface where users will be able to search for something by entering a text string.

I would like to update the url with an optional param (`query=search_string`) so that when the user returns to their search with the back button they return to the same search already loaded.  (I'll also be doing the same thing for the page they are on)

**What would be the appropriate way to add optional params with ngrx?**

My thought is to put this into `BookEffects` since we do not want to update the route prior to the debounce time.  But for some reason that doesn't feel right...

[Edit]
To expand on this further, when the user navigates back to the search page, the search would need to be bootstrapped somehow.  So my thought would be to also modify the `FindBookPageComponent` to include:

```
constructor(..., private route: ActivatedRoute) {
  ...
}

ngOnInit() {
  let query = this.route.snapshot.params['query'];
  if (query) {
    this.store.dispatch(new book.SearchAction(query));
  }
}
```

This still feels awkward because there would be an unnatural  delay before the search results appear due to the `debounce` in the `SearchAction`.  **So does this mean we should also create a separate search action: `ImmediateSearchAction`?**

Answer (score 0):

Nothing in ngrx says how you should implement this it's up to you.

You could make ImmediateSearchAction and use debounce in SearchAction effect to transform it to immediate search. By doing this you can easily reuse existing reducers and still keep actions separated by context.

What I would do:

- Create new UserInputSearchAction, ( this is the debounced one )
- Create new UrlSearchAction, which maps via effect to SearchAction
- Make SearchAction immediate

Recommended reading / videos:

- About ngrx lingo and examples https://blog.nrwl.io/ngrx-patterns-and-techniques-f46126e2b1e5
- About action hygiene (why divide this into 3 actions) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JmnsEvoy-gY